# AES ECB mode encrypt in java and decrypt in ruby

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, encryption, cryptography, aes

I have to encryption method which write in java. My encryption java code:

```
public static String encrypt(String content, String sKey) {
  try {
    SecretKey secretKey = null;
    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    secureRandom.setSeed(sKey.getBytes());
    kgen.init(128, secureRandom);
    secretKey = kgen.generateKey();
    byte[] enCodeFormat = secretKey.getEncoded();
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(enCodeFormat, "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

    byte[] byteContent = content.getBytes("utf-8");
    byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(byteContent);

    return ByteUtil.parseByte2HexStr(result);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return content;
}


## ByteUtil.java
...
public static String parseByte2HexStr(byte buf[]) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        String hex = Integer.toHexString(buf[i] & 0xFF);
        if (hex.length() == 1) {
            hex = '0' + hex;
        }
        sb.append(hex.toUpperCase());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

**My ruby decryption code (not work):**

```
require "openssl"
require 'digest/sha2'
require 'base64'

def decryption(encrypted, key)
  decipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(128, :ECB)
  decipher.decrypt
  decipher.padding = 0
  decipher.key = [key].pack('H*')

  encrypted = [encrypted].pack('H*')
  plain = decipher.update(encrypted) + decipher.final

  p plain
  p plain.unpack('s*')
  p plain.unpack('m*')
  p plain.unpack('u*')
  p plain.unpack('h*')
  p plain.unpack('a*')
end
```

Anyone can help? thanks in advance!!!

when I use 'ef3192c8803a47cb829d487dd2f78a3d' as key, and encrypt 'helloworld' with my java code, I get '3CAEF382FB17A045EADDEFC72D3D0362', But when I try use my ruby code to decrypt it, I call

```
decryption('3CAEF382FB17A045EADDEFC72D3D0362', 'ef3192c8803a47cb829d487dd2f78a3d')
```

I can't get 'helloworld', So I think the decryption code is not work.

**Java decryption code( it's works)**

```
public static String decrypt(String content, String sKey) {
    try {
        SecretKey secretKey = null;
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        secureRandom.setSeed(sKey.getBytes());
        kgen.init(128, secureRandom);
        secretKey = kgen.generateKey();

        byte[] data = ByteUtil.parseHexStr2Byte(content);
        byte[] enCodeFormat = secretKey.getEncoded();

        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(enCodeFormat, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(data);
        return new String(result, "UTF-8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return content;
}
```

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific than "not work".

Comment: In particular, you need to show the input to your Java code, its output, and what the deciphered output from the Ruby code is. Off the top of my head, I note that you're not setting a mode for the Java code (default is implementation-dependent), and you're disabling padding on the Ruby side when it's enabled on the Java side.  Also, you're printing the hex representation of the encrypted bytes on the Java side but haven't shown any Ruby code where you're unpacking the hex string back into a byte array.

Comment: @chrylis, thanks for your help, I think java AES default use ECB mode

Comment: No, the Oracle implementation by default uses ECB. You can't depend on that any more than you can depend on the platform encoding. Specify both.

Comment: @chrylis, the problem is the encryption is some other's code, and my work is implement a decryption procedure for this encryption, I can't make any change to the encryption

Comment: Your bug is in not decoding the hex digits into bytes before decrypting, but specifying just a bare `"AES"` is a bug that needs to be filed appropriately.

Comment: even i use [encrypted].pack('H*') before the decryption, it still not work

Comment: The java code generates a random encryption key, encrypts with it, and then throws it away. You will not be able to decrypt the message in ruby unless you preserve the key generated in java.

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen If the PRNG is sufficiently clearly defined, it should be possible to replicate the key generation on Ruby. That said, the Java encryption method is just all-around bad and really needs an overhaul.

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen I run the java code many times and I get the same encrypted result. and I have a java decryption code which is works

Comment: @lfx_cool Yep - missed that you initialize your secureRandom with the key. And those you generate the same key each time. The big question is why do you pass your key through a secureRandom in the first place? Now you would need to do the exact same in ruby as well. It does not add extra security, but it does add extra trouble.

Comment: java code is wrote by parter company, I can't change it, but I need to     implement a decryption method in ruby, then I can send http request which can processed by them, I stuck here a long time...

Comment: @lfx_cool OK - I have added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java implementation is sort of messed up.

The **actual AES key** used to encrypt in the java code is the `SecretKey secretKey` generated with the following code using the `String sKey` as input:

```
    SecretKey secretKey = null;
    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    secureRandom.setSeed(sKey.getBytes());
    kgen.init(128, secureRandom);
    secretKey = kgen.generateKey();
    byte[] enCodeFormat = secretKey.getEncoded();
```

To be able to decrypt in the **ruby** code, you need the content of `SecretKey secretKey`. Try adding this trace statement after above code:

```
    System.out.println("Key: " + ByteUtil.parseByte2HexStr(enCodeFormat));
```

And use that as the key in your **ruby** call.

Comment: ByteUtil.parseByte2HexStr(enCodeFormat) get the print ACB0FA221014CE61715EE9936BC7B659, And I use this as key to decrypte in  ruby, I get ["helloworld\x06\x06\x06\x06\x06\x06"], can't understand it

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the same key on both ends. In the Java encryption, you're using the key as the seed for a random-number generator, and then using the output of *that* as the key. On the Ruby side, you're directly using the input value as the key.